# Finding system information missing from dmi

Tags: linux

I'm attempting to get model/serial numbers for parts of an HP server but `dmidecode` is yielding "not specified." Is there any way to get this information without a screwdriver?
I've already checked `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi` manually but obviously didn't find anything that `dmidecode` didn't pull already. I'm doing all this with Ubuntu running off of a USB because it was around.

Comment: So you do not have physical access to the server?

Comment: Does it have a ILO.

Comment: have tried installing `sudo apt-get install sysinfo` this